# Laravel - Query scopes across models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In a nutshell, I want to create a function that my query scopes can use across multiple models:

```
public function scopeNormaliseCurrency($query,$targetCurrency) {

    return $query->normaliseCurrencyFields(
        ['cost_per_day','cost_per_week'],
        $targetCurrency
    );

}
```

I have got my logic working within this scope function no problem, but I want to make this code available to all my models, as there are multiple currency fields in different tables and I don't want to be replicating the code in each query scope - only specify the columns that need attention.

So, where would I make my function `normaliseCurrencyFields`? I have extended the `Model` class as well as used the `newCollection` keyword to extend `Collection` but both result in `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::normaliseCurrencyFields()` errors.

I have looked into [Global Scoping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#global-scopes) but this seems to be localised to a Model.

Am I along the right lines? Should I be targeting Eloquent specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an abstract base model that extends eloquent then extend it with the classes you want to have access to it. I do this for searching functions, uuid creation, and class code functions. So that all of my saved models are required to have to certain attributes and access to my searching functions. For instance I created a static search function getobjectbyid(). So that when extended I can call it like so:

```
$user = User::getobjectbyid('habwiifnbrklsnbbd1938');
```

Thus way I know I am getting a user object back.

My base model:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: amac
 * Date: 6/5/17
 * Time: 12:45 AM
 */

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

abstract class Model extends Eloquent
{

    protected $guarded = [
        'class_code',
        'id'
    ];

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
        parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent

        $this->class_code = \App\Enums\EnumClassCode::getValueByKey(get_class($this));

        $this->id = $this->class_code . uniqid();

        return $this;

    }


    public static function getObjectById($id){
        $class = get_called_class();
        $results = $class::find($id);
        return $results;

    }

    public static function getAllObjects(){
        $class = get_called_class();
        return $class::all();
    }
```

my user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Mockery\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

use App\Model as Model;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'contact', 'username', 'email_address'
    ];

    /**
     * The column name of the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rememberTokenName = 'remember_token';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token', 'active'
    ];

    /**
     * the attributes that should be guarded from Mass Assignment
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at', 'password_hash'
    ];

    /**
     * Define table to be used with this model. It defaults and assumes table names will have an s added to the end.
     *for instance App\User table by default would be users
     */
    protected $table = "user";

    /**
     * We have a non incrementing primary key
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * relationships
     */
    public function contact(){
//        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class, 'id', 'contact_id');
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class);
    }


    public function customers(){
//        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class, 'id', 'contact_id');
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
    }

    /**
     * User constructor.
     * @param array $attributes
     */
    public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
        parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
        // Your construct code.

        $this->active = 1;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @param $password string
     * set user password_hash
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPassword($password){
        // TODO Password Validation
        try{
            $this->isActive();
            $this->password_hash = Hash::make($password);
            $this->save();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Returns whether or not this use is active.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive(){
        if($this->active) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Throw new Exception('This user is not active. Therefore you cannot change the password', 409);
        }
    }


    public function getEmailUsername(){
        $contact = Contact::getObjectById($this->contact_id);

        $email = Email::getObjectById($contact->email_id);

        return $email->username_prefix;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * getFullName
     * returns concatenated first and last name of user.
     */
    public function getFullName(){
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }


    /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName(){
        return $this->getKeyName();

    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()};
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password_hash;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken(){
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            return $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()};
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()} = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return $this->rememberTokenName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset(){

    }

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token){

    }

    public function validateAddress(){

    }


}
```

a TestController:

```
public function test(){
        $user = User::getObjectById('USR594079ca59746');

        $customers = array();

        foreach ($user->customers as $customer){

            $contact = Contact::getObjectById($customer->contact_id);

            $name = PersonName::getObjectById($contact->personname_id);

            $c = new \stdClass();

            $c->id = $customer->id;
            $c->name = $name->preferred_name;

            $customers[] = $c;
        }

        $response = response()->json($customers);

        return $response;
}
```

Take note on how getObjectById is extended and available to my other classes that extend my base model. Also I do not have to specify in my user model an 'id' or 'class_code' and when my user model is constructed it calls the parent constructor which is the constructor on my base model that handles 'id' and 'class_code'.

Comment: Thanks but I'm struggling to implement this. I had created a new class, `ModelPlus` that extended Eloquent's `Model` and created my `normaliseCurrencyFields()` method in there. I can access this within my respecitve Models using `$this->normaliseCurrencyFields()` but I'm obviously not going the right way about it as I cannot chain from the query. I *think* I've tried to use a second abstracted class but same result. Any chance you could provide code samples please?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Really helpful - I see where I was going wrong now. I was intending to go through a dedicated scope method in each model to call on a helper function. The right way of doing it was instead moving this scope function to the base model. The scope is now active on all models extended from the custom base and I can chain directly from the controller. Cheers @Alex Mac 

Comment: Awesome glad to of helped!!